# Sharepoint Designer 2010 Task Workflow handling Out of Office replies

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, outlook, approval-process

Environment: Sharepoint 2010, Sharepoint Designer 2010, Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2010.

I have an Approval workflow and so far it works properly. It is handling the way I wanted it to work.

There was a scenario that I am trying to find a solution to. The approval task is serial and it has been assigned to 5 different users. And one of the users has an out of office automatic reply.

Is there a way to automate if the user has an out of office reply so it is not sent to that user? Or at least identify if the user has an out of office reply and allow another specific user to be notified and allow that user to have the permission to approve the task?